# How do I make my armature visible through my mesh

Tags: rigging, objects, visibility

There seems to be no option to see my armature through my mesh unless I use wireframe but I want to see how it looks while it's textured to see how it stretches the UV's. I can't believe that this question hasn't been asked before since the major 2.8 release came out and swapped everything around.
Someone told me to check the properties tab but no luck.

Answer (score 1):

So some workarounds might be like previously mentioned, use wireframe. I found this really annoying and tedious. Then I found some help and told me to use x-ray, that is actually not the same thing in 2.8 and now will make your mesh see-through. You can do this by going to your header on the 3d viewport and it should be the last tab to your right. That should bring a drop-down menu out and there should be a checkbox that says "x-ray"

So the REAL solution is that they changed the name from, "x-ray" to "in-front". Now you can find this by going to your properties window and under the "object" tab there should be a header that reads "Viewport Display". This is where the "in-front" option is.